# Parsing XML file in Julia

Tags: xml, parsing, julia

I am trying to parse an XML file in Julia which starts like this (sorry I cannot share the entire file for data protection):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Device Name="Bob; ID=Unknown" Sources="1" GainFactor="20" Filter ="1">
    <Channels>
    </Channels>
</Device>
```

......
and continues.
I need to get the value of the GainFactor part of the root name. I have tried using LightXML and EzXML, but can only seem to parse things from the child roots <Channels> and so on. Please could someone suggest a way of getting the info from the root part <Device....>. Thank you in advance, I am new to Julia!
I've tried something like:

```
using EzXML

xdoc = readxml(FILE_NAME)
xroot = root(xdoc) 

for i in eachelement(xroot)
    println(i)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the sample XML. <strike>It would have been nice to make the sample XML a complete XML with appropriate closing tags.</strike> In any case, playing around with it, the following does the OP's request:

```
gfactor = nothing
for attr in eachattribute(xroot)
    if nodename(attr)=="GainFactor"
        gfactor = tryparse(Int, nodecontent(attr))
    end
end
if isnothing(gfactor)  # could not parse/find gfactor
    gfactor = 10 # some default value or error
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly, in future will add a complete sample. Can't upvote since I don't have enough rep yet, but have approved :)